# Spring Boot datasource database connection config doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

**Environment:**
Java Version: 1.8
Spring Boot Version: 2.0.0.M7

**Error Description:**
The following are the configuration I set in my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=1000  
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=2
```

But when I ran a load test, the error message showed "Connection is not available, request timed out after 30038ms."

It looks like configuration doesn't work, time out should be around 1000ms

Comment: Are you using Tomcat connection pool?

Comment: Check `DataSource` exact implementation (in debugger for example), it can be default spring datasource, not tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

the properties you set are correct, but thefore you have to make sure that JDBC connection is properly recognized from logs of application, cause based on it properties will take affect or not

for example, if you are using mysql, use this SQL command and you will see the process by which will understand was max-active, max-idle applied or not:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```